# Create a div dynamically from existing div

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this script to give me the a id from the existing div, now i am using GET to use that id and take into php and create another div, but what happens, is that whenever i click on the existing div, the page get's refreshed. Can i avoid that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.lcard').click(function(){
    var cid = $(this).attr('id');


 window.location.href = "?cid="+cid;

});
```

Comment: Do you want to append the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would do something like this. Assuming you have your main div with id = 'id'. Your code would be close to this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('id')


div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div')

   /* Fetch your data from database here*/
   newDiv.innerHTML = "some cool text"

   div.appendChild(newDiv)

}.bind(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="orgrinal_div">...DATA...</div>

<script>
$("#orgrinal_div").on("click",function(){
    $(this).append("<div>"+$(this).html()+"</div>");
});
</script>
```